# Trimming zeros in JSONArray in Karate DSL

Tags: karate

I am getting a JSON response with JSONArray having leading zeros. Example, `registrationnumber = ["0000012345", "0000001234", "000123456"]`
I want to remove these zeros and compare with another json response where I get the `registrationNumber =["12345", "1234", "123456"]`

I am trying to do this with my automation in karate-dsl. 
Can someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert to a number just multiply by 1. You should read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

```
* def data = ["0000012345", "0000001234", "000123456"]
* def nums = karate.map(data, function(x){ return parseInt(x) })
* match nums == [12345, 1234, 123456]
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! This actually shows how powerful Karate is.